# Getting back to the Recent projects panel

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

The recent projects **panel** only appear at the opening of QGIS sessions.

Would it be a way to get back to this panel **anytime** (when no project is open obviously).

Getting back to it directly **or** using a script ... any way to achieve this ?

I find the projects "snapshots" so useful to find back projects ...

Comment: After closing the current project (`project -> close`) the recent projects pop up again for me. What happens when you do so?

Comment: lol ... u're right ... i'm so used to get back to another project using _new_ or using the recent projects list int the project menu that i often don't use _project/close_ ... should i delete my question ? ;-)

Comment: You can answer your own question with details to help other users with the same "problem".

Comment: By any chance do u know what is the 'depth' of this history and is it possible to tweak it ? where is the information stored (project paths and snapshots) ? Thanks

Comment: Snapshots are in the user profile folder under previewImages.